# find total components in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a graph with N nodes and M edges. It is a single component.

Now I have to delete a single node from graph, deleting that node might split graph into 1,2 or more components. The count of such components is required for each deleted node.
Note that only a single node is deleted at any point of time.

I need to do this for all the nodes of the graph in a linear time.

Is this possible in linear time?
I am able to do this in O(n^2) by running dfs for each node.

Comment: I'm not sure about whether it's possible in a linear time, but you should be able to reduce the time spent finding the number of components by utilizing the fact that the number of edges `|E|` connected to the removed edge `v` will be the maximum amount of new components minus one. You also only look for a new path between the neighbors of the deleted node `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Read some online resources about "Articulation Point". 
I hope you will get your answer. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/